# How is the derivative of $x\cos x\sin x$ $\frac12\sin2x + x\cos2x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

Find $f'(x)$ when $f(x) = x\cos(x) \sin(x)$

I tried using the product rule on $x\cos x$ and got: 
$$(x\cos x)' = -x\sin x + \cos x$$
then I used the product rule to differentiate $x\cos x\sin x$ and got:
$$(x\cos x \sin x)' = (-x \sin x + \cos x)\sin x+ (x\cos x \cos x)= -x\sin^2x+ \sin x \cos x + x\cos^2x$$
My testbook says the answer is $\frac12\sin2x+ x\cos2x$

Can someone please explain how to achieve the answer shown in my textbook? I am new to calc and trig, and I'm very confused.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A tip: when "I got this but my textbook got that", *if trigonometry is involved*, there's probably an identity that shows your book agrees with you. (Two in this case.) It happens all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. Use,

> $2\sin x\cos x = \sin(2x)$

and

> $\cos^2x-\sin^2x= \cos(2x)$

So that,

$x(\cos^2x-\sin^2x) + \sin x \cos x = x\cos(2x) + \frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$

Comment: thank you, I was unaware of the first rule.

Answer (score 1):

The two answers are equivalent:
$$-x\sin^2x+\sin x\cos x+x\cos^2x=x(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)+\frac12\sin2x=x\cos2x+\frac12\sin2x$$